# Get Math Operator from InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use InputBox to get a math operator

E.g.: `+`. When I replace the operator with the variable it gives an error

> Expected Then or GoTo

**This doesn't work:**

```
Sub NumTest()
Dim Val As Integer

Val = Application.InputBox("Value", "Value", Type:=1)
oper = Application.InputBox("Op")
rcell = Range("D2")

If rcell oper Val = True Then
    MsgBox "True"
End If
End Sub
```

**This does work:**

```
Sub NumTest()
Dim Val As Integer

Val = Application.InputBox("Value", "Value", Type:=1)
oper = Application.InputBox("Op")
rcell = Range("D2")

If rcell > Val = True Then
    MsgBox "True"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Application.Evaluate(rcell & oper & Val) Then`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a string and use Application.Evaluate:

```
Sub NumTest()
    Dim Val As Integer
    Val = Application.InputBox("Value", "Value", Type:=1)
    Dim oper As String
    oper = Application.InputBox("Op")
    Dim rcell As String
    rcell = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")

    If Application.Evaluate(rcell & oper & Val) Then
        MsgBox "True"
    Else
        MsgBox "False"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method where you can specify the context in which the formula gets evaluated. `Application.Evaluate` uses the Active sheet, which might meet your needs right now but will come back to bite you later...

Comment: `rng.Parent.Evaluate(...)` will ensure Excel calculates the result using the correct worksheet as the source of the cell values.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers he is saying use : `If ActiveSheet.Evaluate(rcell & oper & Val) Then` instead.  If refering to cells use the sheets.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers if using `rng.Parent.Evaluate(...)` does not solve your current issue, ask a new question showing the actual code.

Comment: @ScottCraner The issue is that the `Val` doesn't accept `0.#` as it sets `Val = 0`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers then change the declaration from `Integer` to `Double`

Answer (score 3):

Operators are syntactic language elements, and they're not up for grabs: you can't just decide to use some identifier / string variable, and in the name of its string content being some operator, treat it as an operator: syntactically, it's a variable, not an operator.

So the compiler has no idea what you mean here:

```
If rcell oper Val = True Then
```

Because the expression `rcell oper Val = True` makes no sense, syntatically:

```
If variable1 variable2 variable3 = True Then
```

Note that the `= True` part is redundant: a Boolean expression can only ever be `True` or `False`; if the expression is `True`, it won't be truer if you compare it to the literal value `True`.

Using `Application.Evaluate` will work, so long as you're willing to let Excel do the work. If your code needs to be ported over to any other VBA host application, then you can't do that. Well you *could*, but it *could* be overkill to reference the Excel object model only to leverage its calc engine to evaluate simple expressions.

What you *can* do, is map the legal `oper` values to functions. Make some `ExpressionEvaluator` class module for this.

```
Public Function AddOperator(ByVal LHS As Variant, ByVal RHS As Variant) As Variant
    AddOperator = LHS + RHS ' let VBA deal with type mismatches & other issues
End Function

Public Function SubtractOperator(ByVal LHS As Variant, ByVal RHS As Variant) As Variant
    SubtractOperator = LHS - RHS ' let VBA deal with type mismatches & other issues
End Function

Public Function LessThanOperator(ByVal LHS As Variant, ByVal RHS As Variant) As Boolean
    LessThanOperator = LHS < RHS ' let VBA deal with type mismatches & other issues
End Function

'...

Public Property Get BinaryOperatorMap() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Static map As Scripting.Dictionary
    If map Is Nothing Then
        Set map = New Scripting.Dictionary
        map.Add "+", "AddOperator"
        map.Add "-", "SubtractOperator"
        map.Add "<", "LessThanOperator"
        '...
    End If
    Set BinaryOperatorMap = map
End Property
```

And then you can parse the user-provided inputs and use `CallByName` to invoke the mapped function and feed it the `LHS` and `RHS` arguments:

```
Public Function Evaluate(ByVal LHS As Variant, ByVal oper As String, ByVal RHS As Variant) As Variant
    Dim operation As String
    operation = BinaryOperatorMap(oper)

    Dim instance As Object
    Set instance = Me
    Evaluate = CallByName(instance, operation, vbMethod, LHS, RHS)
End Function
```

Note that `CallByName` needs an object instance; that's why you need the operations to be implemented in a class module.