# Is there anyway to use string as if statement condition in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text in a cell, containing a condition statement like "0 <= a < 100" and this condition can dynamically be changed to something like:

- "a < 50 or a > 100"
- "500 > a > 100"
- "a > 100"

, based on the value in the cell.

Is there anyway in VBA to convert such strings into normal IF-condition like *0 <= a and a < 100*.

For example:

```
a = 50
Str_condition = "0 <= a < 100"
If Convert(Str_condition, a) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Comment: You mean... `If a >= 0 And a < 100 Then` ? You cant convert it from what you are suggesting.

Comment: You could potentially use `Application.Evaluate` but you'd have to transform the string for Excel to evaluate it correctly. This seems like an X-Y problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot set the condition statically as it might change to something else, based on the condition in a cell.

Comment: Not an exact match but the answer is similar to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181541/get-math-operator-from-inputbox/59181640#59181640

Comment: Why not using a `Select Case`?

Comment: the big problem is that you will either need to teach your user group the proper method to use AND or OR, or you will need to parse the string in the code to put it in proper context of a Excel Formula ie `AND()` or `OR()` then use Worksheet Evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this seems to work for single-condition formulas:

```
Sub t()
Dim a As Long
a = 50

Dim str_cond As String
str_cond = "0 <= a"
str_cond = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(str_cond, "a", a)
Debug.Print Evaluate(str_cond)
End Sub
```

returns `True`.